# Filter TFS Pending Changes by Shelveset/Workspace Diff

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs

While working in two workspaces, I have one workspace which builds on the content of another workspace. One workspace has been reviewed and is complete, but I have to wait to check it in until some others check in their changes.

While waiting for this, I finished the work in my dependent workspace and would like it reviewed, but I don't want a reviewer to have to wade through all of the changes in the independent changeset to find the couple of changes I've made in the dependent changeset.

Looking at changes in the same files is fine, but if possible I'd like to filter out files from the Included Changes (which is what's sent out for the reviewer to check).

Is there a simple way to do this aside from manually?

Answer (score 2):

To filter out files from the Included Changes pane, please go to Included Changes -> Show Filter.

[image]

You will be provided one search box in which you can find any file you want, after you find that file, you can then right click it and choose "Exclude". Then, you can request review with files you want to have the review.

Comment: I appreciate the response, but this seems like just a faster way of doing it manually. What I was really hoping was for an automated way of diffing the changesets, or at least being able to create a custom filter based on one changeset. I think this is not supported, though there may be an extension which adds it.

Comment: Found this when I encountered an issue where my pending changes wasn't showing me all my changes. I didn't noticed for a while that a filter had been applied. Would be nice if they had a UI clue that a filter was applied.